# How to define an event that is triggered at certain DateTime

Tags: f#

My goal is to create an event which is triggered when certain date-time conditions are met - for example when the seconds value of DateTime.Now is changed (later it should be the month value)

I'm trying this:

```
type Timer() =
    
    let timerEvent = new Event<System.DateTime>()

    let cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()

    member this.onSecondTick = 
        let loop =         
            async {
                while true do
                    let time = System.DateTime.Now
                    let tickDecrTime = time - System.TimeSpan(1)
                    if time.Second <> tickDecrTime.Second then
                        timerEvent.Trigger(time)
                    else
                        let offset = 200;
                        let sleepTime = 1000 - time.Millisecond - offset;
                        if sleepTime > 0 then do! Async.Sleep(sleepTime)
            }

        Async.Start(loop, cts.Token)
        
        timerEvent.Publish

    interface System.IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() = 
            printfn "Disposed"
            cts.Cancel()

    member this.Dispose() =( this:> System.IDisposable).Dispose()
```

If I'm not using the Async.Sleep in the else branch of async{} then during the execution with FSI the NET Host process processor time rises up to 20% on my core i5, which I believe shouldn't work like that. If I'm using Async.Sleep then sometimes it misses the seconds events depending on the offset milliseconds value which I'm subtracting from the overall milliseconds period to get the estimation of the time for which I could send to sleep the async process.
Is there a better way to trigger date-time related events than checking condition on DateTime.Now in the infinite loop?

Comment: Without looking too carefully at your code, it looks like a polling loop. Polling kills the machine. Never use polling, unless it absolutely is the last resort. Even then, it is highly unprofessional. Instead, calculate how long to Async.Sleep to reach the time when there's actual work to do. You should perhaps use a library like Quarz.NET or similar - there's also another one, but I don't remember its name.

Comment: @BentTranberg I felt that lnfinite loop was a bad idea, recursive function seem to work better here from the point of processor load.

Comment: Recursive function is just another name for polling loop in this case. You shouldn't have any load at all. Stop polling DateTime.Now in a loop, and instead calculate how long to wait in one call to Async.Sleep.

Comment: The other library I was thinking of is Hangfire. One of the two libraries can help you trigger exactly at some clock second, minute, etc.